# Desplegar un select dentro dentro de un modal PHP - Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, html5, modal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Un saludo,
Buenas a todos, me ecnuentro trabajando en un proyecto en laravel y uso Mysql, en este caso necesito crear una transaccion dentro de un **modal**, donde tengo los campos:

- Id
- Name
- Description
- Type

Pero el problema ocurre cuando en el campo de type al ser un **select** no me despliega las opcion que necesito (ingreso,egreso). Si me pueden ayudar a como hacer que me muestre estas dos opciones.
Les dejo el codigo del modal:

```
<div id="modalct" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
  <h5><b>Crear una nueva transaccion</b></h5>
</div>
<form class="col s12" method="POST" action="{{ action('TransactionController@store') }}">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input placeholder="@lang('app.name')" id="name" type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
          <label for="name">@lang('app.name')</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <textarea placeholder="@lang('app.description')" id="description" name="description" class="materialize-textarea">{{ old('description') }}</textarea>
          <label for="description">@lang('app.description')</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <select name="type" id="type">
            <option value="" disabled selected>@lang('app.choose-option')</option>
            <option value="1">Ingreso</option>
            <option value="2">Egreso</option>
          </select>
          <label for="type">@lang('app.type-transaction')</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <button class="btn cyan waves-effect waves-light right" type="submit" name="action">@lang('app.submit')
            <i class="material-icons right">edit</i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Hola, según veo en la documentación de [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/select.html#initialization) (que quiero pensar es lo que utilizas) es necesario inicializar el select para que este se vea.En caso de que lo estés haciendo y aun así no funciona, podrías poner una imagen de lo que se ve actualmente en tu modal?

Comment: No entiendo qué librerías usas para el front-end y también si puedes simular el error para poder ayudarte

Comment: Ya esta la imagen del modal actulamente, pero no se si son las clases en los div pero no me despliega las opciones. Si uso materialize.

Comment: Listo ya lo pude solucionar el error fue error mio al llamar al modal dentro del show. Gracias por sus consejos.